# HTTPResponse object has no attribute 'geturl'

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

Есть код

```
import time, sys, threading, urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager(timeout = urllib3.util.timeout.Timeout(connect=5.0, read=20.0))

try:
    page = http.request('GET','https://wordpress.org')
    print(page.status)
    print(page.geturl())

except BaseException as e:
    print(e)
```

На локальной машине (ubuntu) работает. На сервере почему-то нет. Возвращает:

```
200
'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'geturl'
```

Версия питона 3.7.5 на сервере и локалке.

Как исправить?

---

**UPD.**

Версия `urllib3` на сервере `1.22`, а на локалке `1.24.1`

Comment: А что выводят `print(urllib3.__version__)`, `print(page.__class__)` и `print(dir(page))`? На текущей версии `urllib3` тот метод присутствует: https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/6322ad570c55fc0b51097ffcaeb9836358f27adb/src/urllib3/response.py#L783

Comment: 1.24.1
<class 'urllib3.response.HTTPResponse'>

Comment: на сервере 1.22
<class 'urllib3.response.HTTPResponse'>

Comment: все понял, обновил urllib3, заработало

Comment: В этом и причина... обновите на сервере urllib3 через `pip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На версии [1.22](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/releases/tag/1.22) у `HTTPResponse` еще нет метода [geturl](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/6322ad570c55fc0b51097ffcaeb9836358f27adb/src/urllib3/response.py#L783).

Поэтому, обновите [urllib3](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3) до актуальной версии:

- `pip install --upgrade urllib3`

---

Метод [geturl](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/6322ad570c55fc0b51097ffcaeb9836358f27adb/src/urllib3/response.py#L783) появился **30/08/2018** в ["Implements #1272 by adding a geturl method to HTTPResponse objects"](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/pull/1382), а версия [1.22](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/releases/tag/1.22) вышла **20/07/2017**